# AWS email forwarding from EC2, but impossible to verify a non-existent address.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've seen similar posts out there, but not quite the same thing that I'm asking.

I have a web site (www.example.com) hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. I want mail sent to "contactus@example.com" to go to several people, whose addresses may be of varying domains.

I tried setting up SES, but I need to "verify the address" (I have already verified the domain). But that "contactus" address is not a mailbox and currently does not forward to anyone, so there's no way I can verify it. I feel like this is a chicken and the egg problem.

I've read on here that mail relaying is a notably absent feature of AWS SES. I've seen Rube-Goldberg type solutions involving SES, Lamba and S3, but that seems needlessly complicated.

I simply want to "contactus@example.com" to forward mail to john@foo.com, bob@bar.com, etc... and I'm not committed to using SES; I am open to other solutions that can be run from the EC2 instance. How do I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you handling email on your domain?

Comment: That's just it- we're not. We were hosting it on the our server itself on with our old provider, but that doesn't appear to be possible on EC2.

Comment: If you aren't receiving mail anywhere, then there's nowhere that can possibly run the mailing list you want. First, arrange for your email to be hosted somewhere.

Comment: Aaah, yes. I went and found simple email hosting and have used that to get the addresses verified. Such a simple and obvious solution that somehow escaped me. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered if you've figured it out. You can answer your own questions and mark them answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to subscribe to a mail hosting provider. (Pretty obvious in hind sight.) I went ahead and selected a mail provider and I am now set. Thank you!